# Need help understanding parent nodes in binary search trees

Tags: c, parent, nodes, binary-search-tree

The below code is a function that inserts a node into the correct location in the tree. What I don't understand is what the parent node actually represents.  When it says `root -> left -> parent = root -> left`, what does it mean? Isn't that setting root's left's parent to be itself? 
Shouldn't it be `root -> left -> parent = root` instead, because we want root's left-child's parent to be root and not left-child itself? Can you please clarify parent nodes for me, Thank you.

```
Node * insert(Node *root, int item) {
  if (root == NULL)
    return newNode(item);

  if (item <= root -> info)
    if (root -> left == NULL) {
      root -> left = newNode(item);
      root -> left -> parent = root -> left;      //**line of interest**
    }
    else
      insert(root -> left, item);
  else
    if (root -> right == NULL) {
      root -> right = newNode(item);
      root -> right -> parent = root -> right;
    }
    else
      insert(root -> right, item);
  return root;
}
```

Comment: Is this code working correctly? Your assumption seems to be right: looks like root->left->parent = root; should be the command.

Comment: @FernandoAires Wouldn't `root->left->parent` be `root` itself?

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote...

Comment: @FernandoAires Is there a reason for that command? It's saying `root = root`...

Comment: No, it is saying take the node pointed to by root's left pointer and set its parent pointer to the address of root.

Comment: @Fred, so is the code correct? If we are setting the root's left's parent pointer to address of root then why is being assigned to root->left?

Comment: Without seeing the declaration of Node, I can't tell for sure. But yes, I think it should be `root->left->parent = root` and the current assignment is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description i think the node class will be,

```
class node{
   int info;
   node *left;
   node *right;
   node *parent;
};
```

Now in BST there will be a root node in which the parent will be NULL. Suppose we insert the first value.(let it be 5)
Now root has 5 obviously. `root->left` is null and `root->right` is null.

If you insert 2 now then 2 will be in left side of the root.

so root->left will be 2. Now lets simplify this, as by `root->left` we mean a node, not a value.
Thus `root->left->info = 2;`.
Now there is one more thing to do. We set the value of `root->left`. Now what is the parent of `root->left`? That will be root,
so `root->left->parent = root;`

Now if you insert another data (let it be 1) then

```
root->left->left->info = 1;
root->left->left->parent = root->left;
```

So your code did not simplify things for inserting a node in BST.

What I would do is,

```
 Node n = new node();
 n = newNode(item); //as you wrote
 n->parent = root->left.
```

Comment: The assignment of `root->left` to `n->parent` is correct only for the case where root is two levels above the newly inserted `n`. Also note the `root->left` node is not pointed to the new left node, so the new node has not been inserted into the tree and cannot be reached from the root.